# Constructor error "call to this must be first statement in constructor"

Tags: java

I am writing some code for a school assignment, and I am not sure why I keep getting the compilation error: "call to this must be first statement in constructor." I'm supposed to create a student with the name Student instead of an inputted name.

```
public void newStudent( ){
   this("Student");
   //Error occurs here ^
}

public void newStudent(String student)
{
   studentAndStatus[studentCount] [0] = student;
   for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
       grades[studentCount] [i] = 0;
   }
   studentCount++;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for the whole `class`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to create an instance of a class, you should use a constructor. The constructor has the same name as the class and no declared return type, for example

```
public class Student {
    public Student() {
        this("Student");
    }

    public Student(String name) {
        //Whatever you want to do...
    }
}
```

In your case the error occurs, because you can only call `this` in a constructor. Since your class propably is not called `newStudent` and the method `newStudent()` has a return type, the method `newStudent()` is not a constructor and therefore `this` cannot be called.

Comment: Even if it were called `newStudent`, there's the `void`.

Comment: @chrylis You are right, I updated the answer accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I solved it by switching this("Student") to newStudent("Student").

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `newStudent()` is a method which is overloaded because **constructors can't have a return type**.

`this(arguments)` can be used only for constructor calls, but you are overloading the `newStudent()` methods, so if you wanted call the `newStudent(String student)`, you can do that as shown below:

```
public void newStudent( ){
   newStudent("Student");//calls the overloaded method
}
```

Comment: It would need to be `static` as well.

Comment: why it should be `static`?

Comment: If `newStudent()` is a factory method, then it needs to (1) return the class (e.g. `Student`), instead of void; and (2) it should be static, unless it's specifically a method that creates a new student that has some relation to an existing student.  If `newStudent` has some other purpose, then that doesn't apply, but it appears that's what the OP was trying to do, maybe.  I don't know, since `newStudent` isn't a descriptive enough name to figure out what a method's purpose is.